# JQuery List items fadeIn and fadeOut

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying the fadeIn/fadeOut effect on list items. The element should fadeIn quickly but fadeOut after 3 seconds. I am trying to figure out what is wrong with my code.

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        #eyebrowBanner li {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
    <script
            src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function(){

            function startAnimations() {
                $("#eyebrowBanner li").hide();

                function loop() {
                    var $li = $("#eyebrowBanner li:first-child").fadeIn(400, function () {
                        $li.fadeOut(3000, function () {
                            $li.appendTo('#eyebrowBanner');
                            loop()
                        })
                    });
                }
                loop()
            }

            startAnimations();


        });
    </script>
</head>


<body>

    <ul id="eyeBrowBanner">

        <li>items 1</li>
        <li>items 2</li>
        <li>items 3</li>


    </ul>



</body>
```

Comment: You have mentioned about expected behaviour but you have mentioned nothing about what is happening right now with your current code? Is it working for just one item or 2 items or else?

Comment: Rory this only takes the fadeIn impact. If i am saying fadeIn(400), and fadeOut to be 3000 , the fadeOut doese not work at all.

Comment: I have tried this, it is somehow not working for me, but let me give it a try again.

Comment: If you're referring to the solution in the duplicate, yes it does: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/mqhcsopk/3/

Comment: it does not seem to be working for me unfortunately, i have put it in my document.ready() function

Comment: check my sample code here. thanks